# Why are all elements not being generated when I use HTTrack or Save All Resources on a HTML web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping

I am trying to see some of the code and the logic behind this online game, called Paper.io.

https://paper-io.com/

To do this, I wanted to save the whole web page and its resources on my computer and see each element react differently.

I have tried to use Save All Resources, chrome extension and HTTrack, web scraping tool, to get all of the resources of this web page.

However, after downloading when I run the index.html, it does not open the web page properly and all of the images/links don't  work.

Any help or recommendation of different tools or strategies will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this website loads the assets using JavaScript and/or CSS, which might not be correctly handled by a non-browser *scraper* (without executing JS). You will need to do some hand work to find the URLs, or use some headless full browser (like `chrome` with `--headless` or some driver like `phantomjs`, `puppeter`, etc), like in [this tutorial with puppeter](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/web-scraping-with-a-headless-browser-a-puppeteer-tutorial).

Comment: Ok, will give it a go. Both HTTrack and Save All Resources do get all of the js, css and other folders which I can visibly see via Inspect Element but as you mentioned there could be some js missing that is not being executed.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any login id then login your account and use same login in HTtrack to clone the website. After login you can download all assets. It will download only HTML, CSS, JS and Images file from any website. you can not download backend codes through it.

Comment: Thanks, this is the main page without any login. You just click play and start playing.